# Is it possible to calculate age-group using Claims Transformations in an Azure B2C Custom Policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have successfully created a custom policy that asks for a user's date-of-birth.

What I would like to do next is tailor the sign-up experience depending on the user's age.

I am hoping that I could do this using claims transformations and preconditions, but looking through the documentation that I have found, I cannot see how to do it. Is it possible?

I have the user's DOB, I think I can get the current date-time (`TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime"` is mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access#capture-terms-of-use-agreement), but I can't see how to calculate the difference (for age), or use the age in a precondition.

The only work-around I can think of is to calculate the age (or age-group), via a REST API claim exchange, but I would prefer not to add more complexity to the system.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

> I have the user's DOB, I think I can get the current date-time
>   (TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime" is mentioned here:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access#capture-terms-of-use-agreement),
>   but I can't see how to calculate the difference (for age), or use the
>   age in a precondition.

The logic that is used to calculate ageGroup from the user's date of birth:

1. Try to find the country by the country code in the list. If the country is not found, fall back to **Default**.
2. If the MinorConsent node is present in the country element:

   a. Calculate the date that the user must have been born on to be
   considered an adult. For example, if the current date is March 14,
   2015, and MinorConsent is 18, the birth date must be no later than
   March 14, 2000.

   b. Compare the minimum birth date with the actual birth date. If the
   minimum birth date is before the user’s birth date, the calculation
   returns Minor as the age group calculation.
3. If the MinorNoConsentRequired node is present in the country element, repeat steps 2a and 2b using the value from MinorNoConsentRequired. The output of 2b returns MinorNoConsentRequired if the minimum birth date is before the user’s birth date.
4. If neither calculation returns true, the calculation returns Adult.

> What I would like to do next is tailor the sign-up experience
>   depending on the user's age.

You could try to use [age gating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/basic-age-gating) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had seen that documentation, but the age groups I need to calculate are not necessarily equivalent to a given country's legal adult/minor ages. Thinking about it, is there any documentation of what ages are used by B2C for this calculation (per country)? With regards to age gating, this is in private preview at the time of writing (Aug 2018), so we cannot use it on our production tenant. For now, I have implemented a REST API claims exchange, which seems to be the right tool for the job for the customisation I need. Cheers!